# How to set vagrant hostname as host OS hostname

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

My host OS is Windows 10. I installed vagrant and virtualbox.
Right now i am hardcoding the hostname of the vagrant like this.

```
config.vm.define "node1" do |node1|
    node1.vm.hostname = "node1.example.com"
    node1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.51"
end
```

How can i assign the vagrant hostname same as my Windows hostname, programatically.

Comment: Try `node1.vm.hostname = ENV['HOSTNAME']`.